# How do I filter the users and latest expired date together?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Some users might have 2 subscriptions. One is expired and another is active.

How do I filter the users and latest expired date from the first table to second table below?

[image: tables]

Comment: What have you tried? SuperUser is not a "do my work for me" site. Tell us what you've tried, where you're stuck etc. and we can try to help.

Comment: I had tried data duplicate remove on email address. But can define the older subscription is erase. It might erase the latest subscription. @Atzmon